# Is there any special configuration needed for @ExponentialRetry in AWS FlowFramework of SWF?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-swf

I am using @ExponentialRetry on the activity, but it is not retrying the activity. Here is my code in Intellij IDEA.

This is my Activities interface

```java
@ExponentialRetry(
    initialRetryIntervalSeconds = 5,
    exceptionsToRetry = IllegalStateException.class,
    maximumAttempts = 5)
String printHello();
```

Implementation:

```java
private boolean check = true;   // on the class level

@Override
public String printHello() {
    System.out.println("In activity 1111");
    if (check) {
        check = false;
        System.out.println("121212121");
        throw new IllegalStateException("showing this for the first time from this activity");
    }
    return "Hello World";
}
```

This is my Workflow implementation class from where I am calling this activity through the activities client, means workflow entry point

```java
@Override
public void helloWorld() {
    handleUnreliableActivity();
}

private void handleUnreliableActivity() {
    new TryCatch() {
        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            Promise<String> result = client.printHello();
            client.printBye(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("In doCatch  **************************");
            throw throwable;
        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

@ExponentialRetry relies on AspectJ for its implementation. Make sure that it is configured correctly.

See [Enabling and configuring AspectJ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html) section from the development guide.